# Listener to be notified just after the Eclipse WORKSPACE gets created?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, workspace, workbench

Can I register a listener to be notified just after the Eclipse workspace is completely created (.metadata completes)?

Two situations:
1. If the workspace exists, notify the listener the location
2. if the workspace is new (the dialog box to ask for to choose a workspace location, in this case, just choose a new location). I would like to be notified that the workspace is just at the time of completely created (for example, .metadata is completely created).

Is that possible to write a plugin to handle event like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Creating the data in the .metadata directory involves many plugins and may not be complete until some time after the UI has been displayed (initializing Java indices can take some time for example). There is nothing that knows when all this has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Workspace is created during org.eclipse.core.resources startup. If your product is properly configured and your code depends on resources plugin you should have no problems - workspace should be there.

If you depend on some other initialization like Java stuff greg-449 mentioned then probably looking for notification hook in JDT is the way to go. Or listen to OSGi events and see what bundles are being started.

Eclipse uses a lot of lazy loading so you might never reach a point where all the plugins are initialized.

Can you drop some details on the use case? That might help.

Comment: My use case is like this:

Comment: My use case is like this: I write a plugin to initialize slf4j/logback, when a user create a new workspace or select the old workspace (while OSGi does its magic until osgi.instance.area gets pointing to the selected workspace location, please note: before the selection dialogbox, osgi.intance.area system property is not available), i will dynamically create file {osgi.instance.area}/configuration/logback.xml and dynamically set logback.configurationFile to that location and reload logback. within logback.xml, the logs will be output to {osg.instance.area}/logs/something.log.

Comment: In this way, the logback configuration and logs only tied to a specific workspace.

Comment: Have a look at ResourcesPlugin.start(BundleContext). You can see that IWorkspace is registered in OSGi as a service after initialization. So, simply waiting for the service (ServiceTracker or Declarative Services) might be a solution.